# How to set tooltip for 4 Textbox together?

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to show the tooltip for 4 text boxes but with one code and I don't want to use the code for each one.

```
private void foundation_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox TB = (TextBox)sender;
    ToolTip tt = new ToolTip();
    tt.Show(letterconverter(Int64.Parse(foundation.Text), ""), TB, 0, 0, 9999);
}
```

This code is working... but I want to use for 3 textboxes too.
textbox1, textbox2, textbox3

Comment: `textBox1.TextChanged += foundation_TextChanged; textBox2.TextChanged += foundation_TextChanged; textBox3.TextChanged += foundation_TextChanged`?

Comment: [ToolTip.Popup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.tooltip.popup) Event → [ToolTip.GetToolTip(Control)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.tooltip.gettooltip) Method

Comment: but in with function? I don't want to write four function like this:

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
textBox1.MouseOver += foundation_TextChanged;
textBox2.MouseOver += foundation_TextChanged;
textBox3.MouseOver += foundation_TextChanged;
textBox4.MouseOver += foundation_TextChanged;
```

Comment: Shouldn't `(...)` simply read  `;`?

Comment: @UweKeim Updated!!